# check if the user had click the submit button already in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

in my blade i have this submit button provided by blade here is my code

```
 {{ Form::submit('Create System User', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
```

i wanted to know if the user clicked the submit button already because i have a code below saying

```
  @if ($errors->any())
    <ul>
        {{ implode('', $errors->all('<p style="color:red" class="error">:message</p>')) }}
    </ul>
    @else
      <script>
          BootstrapDialog.alert('Record Added!');
      </script>
@endif
```

my problem is it keeps displaying the bootstrap alert on load whereas it should only be when the user is successfully created any ideas?

Comment: You should set a flash variable in the controller when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should do the trick:

In your controller method:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    Session::flash('submitted', true);

    // Logic to create user

    return Redirect::back(); // Or whatever your response is
}
```

And then in your view:

```
@if (Session::get('submitted'))
    <script>
        BootstrapDialog.alert('Record Added!');
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: hmm how could i set the value of 'submitted' to false? like after  i redirected to another page then go back, the modal shows again